# Advanced PHP method to add multiple values into SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, oop

I have the following SQL statement entering my database:

```
INSERT INTO table (columneOneName,columnTwoName) VALUES (155,60),(154,60),(153,60),(152,60);
```

That is generated from the below method:

```
public static function batchSave(array $columns, array $newRecords): bool
{        
    global $wpdb;
    $table = self::getTable();
    $count = 0;
    $arrayCount = count($newRecords);
    $colValues = implode(",", $columns);
    $recordValues = '';
    foreach ($newRecords as $record) {
        $count = $count+1;
        $recordValues .= "(";
        $recordValues .= implode(",", array_values($record));
        $recordValues .= ($count == $arrayCount) ? ");" : "),";
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} 
             ($colValues) 
             VALUES $recordValues";
    return (count($wpdb->get_results($query)) > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

I feel that the `foreach` is a little akward, and maybe I am not understanding a more elegant solution to meeting the above query. Is there a more robust logic in my method that can meet the above SQL query?

Is my SQL query not as elegant and thus should be refactored too? As you can see, the columnTwoName values never changes in my SQL but the columnOneName values do change.

Comment: Assuming the source of the data being used in your PHP script be coming from a flat file, then the more sophisticated approach would be to use the `LOAD DATA` tool, which would likely massively outperform your current PHP approach.

Comment: data is stored in a SQL database

Comment: Then you should research using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static function batchSave(array $columns, array $newRecords): bool
{        
    global $wpdb;
    $table = self::getTable();
    $colValues = implode(",", $columns);
    $newRecords = array_map(function($r){ return "(" . implode(",", $r) . ")"; }, $newRecords);
    $newRecords = "(" . implode(",", $newRecords) . ")";
    $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} 
             ($colValues) 
             VALUES $newRecords";
    return count($wpdb->get_results($query)) > 0;
}
```

Comment: getting the following using your method: `WordPress database error Operand should contain 1 column(s) for query`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it slightly different:

```
    public static function batchSave(array $columns, array $newRecords): bool
   {
       global $wpdb;
       $table = self::getTable();
       $colValues = implode(",", $columns);
       $values = [];
       foreach ($newRecords as $record) {
       $values[] = "(" . implode(",", array_values($record)) . ")"; // Good to escape the values also
    }
       $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} 
             ({$colValues}) 
             VALUES " . implode(',', $values);
           return (count($wpdb->get_results($query)) > 0) ? true : false;
   }
```

Just put all the values in an array and implode it with "," instead of checking if we have reached the end.

If you have to do that for a lot of values (like 1mil). You can do something like this to prevent issues regarding the size of the query:

```
 public static function batchSave(array $columns, array $newRecords): bool
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table = self::getTable();
    $colValues = implode(",", $columns);
    $values = [];
    $count = 0;
    $result = true;
    $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} 
             ({$colValues}) 
             VALUES ";
    foreach ($newRecords as $record) {
        $count++;
        $values[] = "(" . implode(",", array_values($record)) . ")"; // Good to escape the values also
        if ($count % 1000 === 0) { //Insert into db each 1000 lines.
            $result &= count($wpdb->get_results($query . implode(',', $values))) > 0;
            $values = [];
        }
    };
    return $result;
}
```

I would also avoid using global variables. Just pass the connection object through parameter if you can so it doesn't look like magic.

If you always have "60" in the second column, you can probably alter the table in your db to default that column to "60" and do not set values in the sql for it.

Comment: this looks great. i will digest and get back with you.
the '60' value was just in the example. both values are dynamic and passed into the method